# Natural preservatives of ink

Tags: metal, safety, metallurgy, plastics, phenols

Would pure compounds like thymol, carvacrol, and cinnamaldehyde work as preservatives of fountain pen ink? I'm specifically interested in three properties -

1. Prevention of growth (mostly fungal) in the bottle of water-based ink.
2. Not be caustic to fountain pen materials - metals, plastics, and rubber.
3. Does not cause an allergy when handling or if some ink ends up on the user's skin.

Would the compounds I mentioned be suitable for this purpose? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Natural also means more organisms may already have a way to deal with it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That I would be willing to accept, but what about the caustic or noxious nature of the chemicals to humans and pens?

Comment: The most noxious chemicals are natural ones. The boundary is not synthetic=bad and natural=good.

Comment: Are thymol, carvacrol and cinnamaldehyde corrosive to metals/plastics/rubber?